# want multi select 2 sided with items displayed alphabetical oreder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I need a multiselect 2 sided pannel for Java Script.
Is there any plug-in for multiselect 2 side with displaying the items alphabetically, that means if there are 1000 items in the list there should be an option for viewing the items alphabetical order.
I used multiselect2side js plug-in but it does not provide alphabetical display of items.
If any body have any idea how to do that, plz share.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `,` after `q: "eRoster"`

try this:-

```
$.ajax({
url: "../cgi-bin/dutyBound.pl",
type: "GET",
data: {
    action: "getEmployees", city: "bangalore",
    curEmployee: "admin", q: "eRoster",
    urlid: "MindTree"
},
success: function (response) {
    // TBD we need better error handling 
    if (myParams.drape) { vidteq.utils.undrapeCurtain(action); }
    successFunc(response, passOn);
},
error: function (response) {
    if (myParams.drape) { vidteq.utils.undrapeCurtain(action); }
    that.gui.io.handleError(response);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be your code, it could be your JSON parser failing.  Do a JSON Lint on your incoming data and maybe that'll be the issue.  In Angular, that got me a few times.